# cx_freeze "zlib not avaiable" error when using multiple threads

Tags: python, zlib, cx-freeze

I have a Python application which works perfectly when run through the standard interpreter, but **not** when frozen with `cx_freeze`.

My application makes use of the python `Threading` module, and typically has around 5 components running, each of which can be individually enabled / disabled in its configuration, and each running in their own individual thread.

With 1 or 2 components enabled, no issue. However, when 3 or more components are enabled, I see the following error message for all or almost all of my threads:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\threading.py", line 637, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "<absolute path to my .py file on disk>", line 21, in run
    from module import screenshot
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1616, in _handle_fromlist
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_and_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<absolute path to my .py file on disk>", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageGrab
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_and_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_and_load_unlocked
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

A few things to note:

- Python is **not** installed at `C:\Python\64-bit\3.3`, so I'm not sure why this path appears in the output above. It is installed in its default location of `C:\Python33`. (Not sure if the path shown above is a dummy one, or maybe the path of the person who compiled one of my dependencies.)
- To reiterate - this starts to constantly happen when I start up more than 2 threads or so. It **never** happens with just 1 active thread, and I have never seen it happen with 2 active threads.
- This issue **only** happens when `cx_freeze` is used. Running it with the Python interpreter produces no errors. I've tried a few different `setup.py` directives (e.g. `appendScriptToLibrary`, `appendScriptToExe`, `copyDependentFiles`, `create_shared_zip`), but the issue is always the same.
- **My code doesn't make use of zip functions - so this must be something specific to the freezing process.**

My thoughts so far:

- I think there is some issue with a thread trying to access the `zlib` or `zipimport` modules when another thread is using them (i.e. has a lock on them). (Interesting that this doesn't happen for 2 threads though.) My Google-ing has made me do some research into the GIL - could this be an issue here? Or, is there any way to allow the threads to only grab a shared lock on a file instead of an exclusive lock?
- Being a relative newbie with `cx_freeze`, I've tried a few different methods of including the `zlib` module in `setup.py`. However, I don't think that this is an issue with `zlib` specifically, since it runs fine outside of `cx_freeze`.

Environment:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Python 3.3 64-bit
- cx_freeze 4.3.2

See http://www.filedropper.com/threadtest for a reproduction of this issue with minimal code.

Comment: Look at the error message: It's from `zipimport`. The `cx_freeze` module builds a zipfile of your frozen library and imports everything out of that. So it's happening when you're trying to `import` a module. And if you look back up the traceback, you can even see which one: `from PIL import ImageGrab`, which itself comes from `from module import screenshot`.

Comment: Anyway, which version of `cx_freeze` do you have? This could be a bug that's been fixed, so if you're not using the latest version, I'd try upgrading before doing anything further. In particular, one of the change log entries for [4.2.3](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releasenotes.html#version-4-2-3) is "Always include the zlib module since the zipimport module requires it, even when compression is not taking place", which sounds like it could be your problem.

Comment: Also, from a quick google, it looks like many people have had problems where the Python zlib module (`zlib.so`/`zlib.pyd`) was built against the zlib shared library (`zlib.dll`/`libz.dll`/`libz.so`/etc.), and cx_freeze included the former, but not the latter; if this seems plausible for your case, see if copying the DLL from wherever you have it into the frozen directory solves the problem. (If so, that's probably not the _best_ solution, but it will tell us what the root problem is, and hopefully help someone suggest the right answer.)

Comment: Thanks for your help and time looking at this. I have cx_freeze 4.3.2, I've updated my post to include the version info. I've tried searching my disk for "zlib.dll", but only found it included with packages like Calibre rather than as part of Windows. Is there a good way I can obtain the "proper" version of this DLL?

Comment: I have reproduced (I think) this issue by creating a minimal test package - see http://www.filedropper.com/threadtest. It runs fine when unfrozen, but when frozen and the number of threads is set to three or more it almost always throws an exception.

Comment: The issue is still there.

Comment: @arnold12 Could you please re-upload your test?

Comment: i has no issues like this until tooday. maybe zlib library updated on my pc.